# How to check whether a solution is feasible for a model in CBC

Tags: coin-or-cbc

I got a solution for my model, how could I know whether it is feasible in CBC?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Express the solution by fixing the MIP-model variables to the values corresponding to the solution and solve it. There are maybe better suited alternatives lile warm-start or primal-heur functionality, but this is much more difficult to understand (e.g. most commercial solvers would say: "solver could ignore your primal solution proposal").

Comment: OK, I'll try it. Thanks.